# Are we permitted to attribute things to Allah's will?

Tags: halal-haram, allah

Does we simple people sin when we attribute things with Allah’s will?

Some examples are:

- A man dies right after his wife confessed that she had an abortion because they did not want to have any more children.
- I pass that exam because I helped my grandmother arranging woods for heating.
- I broke my arm because I was too hard (violent) with my horse.

I know that there is some general goodness about Allah’s payment on this word. And there is connection between interest and war. A long and good life in associated with maintaining family ties.

Answer (score 2):

Hadith - Sahih Bukhari 4:621, Narrated Abu Huraira

Allah's Apostle   said, "Adam and Moses argued with each other. Moses said to Adam, 'You are Adam whose mistake expelled you from Paradise.' Adam said to him, 'You are Moses whom Allah selected as His Messenger and as the one to whom He spoke directly; yet you blame me for a thing which had already been written in my fate before my creation?' " Allah's Apostle   said twice, "So, Adam overpowered Moses."

Allah tests us in this world Humans are diferent from angels in one regard that we have been  given authority to act according to our wish but what result comes is from Allah. We can not attribute result of any act to humans. Humans are free to take decissions and apreciate other's support and pay back but can not say the goodness is because of our acts the reason behind this is that Allah is the best knower and knows the reason of bad or good which happens to us. We dont know it, so say Allah knows best whatever good or bad happened to us instead of saying such and such thing happened because of such and such act or reason.
Read event of "Prophet Musa and Khidr"  Surah 18: 60-82